# proper solution of out of memory issue while displaying all images in layout child of horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, horizontalscrollview

have to show all images without crop or resize.
What should I do easily and what is best ,viewpager, horizontal pager ,pagination or etc ?and some code

Comment: without re scale or down scale not possible to display image without Out of memory . You need to scale image for avoid Out of memory . You need proper method for scale image . if you want i will provide you but it will scale your image

Comment: downvoted because its not clear what the question is about. There a several introductions on how to load and handle images on android and several libraries available i.e. Picasa and Glide. It remains unclear which way you tried and where the problem is. Please be more specific in your question

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go, is not loading a new activity or fragment (which requires memory and leaves the old activity in memory for a while as well), in other words, no `viewpager`, `horizontal pager` or any kind of fragment construction. 
What I would do is load one image in your imageview and use a gesture recognizer or just buttons to go from one image to the next.
Where in your code you just replace the one image with the next one (or with the previous).
For that you need to have the images either in an array, or at least know the order.

By using just one imageview, the old images get freed from memory as fast as you asign the new image to the view. Which would be the least memory you can use.

Hope this was helpfull.